# Chef create config file based on hostname

Tags: chef, automation

New to chef. I have written a recipe to create a file from template based on hostname. If the hostname matches server 1 and server 2 create from template1, else create from default template. However it always creates template1. Please assist :(

This is the code:

```
case node.name
when "server1" || "server2"
 template "template1.conf" do
  source "template1.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
else
 template "template2.conf" do
  source "template2.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
end
```

Comment: Well I have figured this out. Got it working like this:

`code`
case node.name
when "server1" || "server2"
 template "template1.conf" do
  source "template1.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
else
 template "template2.conf" do
  source "template2.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
end
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Well I have figured this out. Got it working like this:

```
case node['hostname']
when 'server1' && 'server2'
 template "template1.conf" do
  source "template1.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
else
 template "template2.conf" do
  source "template2.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
 end
end
```

Comment: This is still not what you want, the correct Ruby syntax is `when 'server1', 'server2'`.